# What are the differences between ODBC and ADO.NET

Tags: oracle, ado.net, odbc

I'm devolving a new module that will connect to an Oracle DB over .net 4.5.1.

1. Should I use ODBC or ADO.NET and what are the differences between them?
2. I read that ADO.NET requires an additional installation of an Oracle's client. Is there any way to use the API without installing the additional module?

Answer (score 14):

[ODBC](http://dbpedia.org/resource/ODBC) is a generic, database-agnostic API for [C](http://dbpedia.org/resource/C_(programming_language))/C+/[C++](http://dbpedia.org/resource/C++)/[ObjectiveC](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Objective-C)-based connections to DBMS, optionally via ODBC driver manager, which typically handles translation between older and newer ODBC API calls and conversion between codepages/charactersets, thence via DBMS-specific ODBC Drivers, which translate the ODBC API calls to the DBMS-specific API and/or DBMS-specific client layer.

```
C/C+/C++-based tool
-> [optional] ODBC driver manager
   -> ODBC driver 
      -> DBMS libraries
         -> DBMS
```

[ADO.NET](http://dbpedia.org/resource/ADO.NET) is a generic, database-agnostic API, for [C#](http://dbpedia.org/resource/C_Sharp_(programming_language))-based connections to DBMS, via DBMS-specific ADO.NET Providers, which translate ADO.NET API calls to the DBMS-specific API and/or DBMS-specific client layer.

```
C#-based tool
-> ADO.NET Provider
   -> DBMS libraries
      -> DBMS
```

([JDBC](http://dbpedia.org/resource/JDBC) and [OLE DB](http://dbpedia.org/resource/OLE_DB) are similar generic, database-agnostic API, respectively for Java- and [Visual Basic](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Visual_Basic)-based connections to DBMS.)

Database vendors often provide "checkbox" (meaning, "yes, we have that") ODBC drivers and ADO.NET providers, as well as [JDBC](http://dbpedia.org/resource/JDBC) drivers and/or [OLE DB](http://dbpedia.org/resource/OLE_DB) providers, which are not necessarily the best performing nor most fully featured options.

[My employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/) produces a [portfolio of high-performance drivers and providers, supporting a wide range of DBMS](http://uda.openlinksw.com/); comparison testing with free two-week evaluation license is encouraged.  "Single-Tier" options generally require the presence of the DBMS client on the same host; "Multi-Tier" options generally remove this requirement on the data consuming host.

C#-based tools cannot connect directly to ODBC drivers, but they can use an *ADO.NET Provider for ODBC Data Sources* to bridge these APIs.  There is no speed advantage inherent to ODBC vs ADO.NET, but there is some speed loss for such bridged solutions, due to the extra layer of API translation.

```
C#-based tool
-> ADO.NET Provider
   -> ODBC driver 
      -> DBMS libraries
         -> DBMS
```

(Microsoft's programming tools use the a Windows built-in ADO.NET-to-ODBC Bridge Provider invisibly and automatically, when you choose an ODBC data source as the target of a C# programming project. My employer also produces such bridge providers, which serve better in many situations.)

Answer (score 3):

ODBC is a generic provider, ODBC drivers are available for almost any data source - even simple CSV-Files.

As a drawback you have fewer functions than in ADO.NET and (at least in theory) less performance.

ADO.NET is more strict to connect to a relational database. Please note, the Oracle provider from Microsoft is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you should not use it for new projects.

Just for completeness, there is also a third provider called [OLE DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB) (see namespace `System.Data.OleDb`). The Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle (`msdaora`) is also [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The provider from Oracle `OraOLEDB.Oracle` has still full support.

For an state-of-the-art connection to Oracle you should use the "Oracle Data Provider for .NET" (ODP.NET), you can download it from here: [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

All ODBC, OLE DB and ODP.NET require an Oracle Client installation. The only way to bypass it, is to use the "ODP.NET Managed Driver". You can download it also from the same location as above.

Comment: Why ADO.NET should (in theory) be faster than ODBC? Could you please elaborate this a little bit more?

Comment: According my knowledge ODBC adds a translation layer between the application and the DBMS. It's one layer more than going directly. According this page [ODBC FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ODBC_FAQ#How_fast_is_ODBC.3F) it appears to be 3% slower, however I did not find the reference at Oracle website directly.

Comment: Yes, this is true for the **Oracle** ODBC Driver as it remaps ODBC calls to their "native" OCI protocol. An old benchmark is still available [here](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjYyqfC8obKAhUMQCYKHYmjCb8QFgguMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kncomputing.com%2Fpapers%2FBenchmarks_SQL_APIs.PDF&usg=AFQjCNEeyGuu9vIRVeWFqS7pfQskttWvxQ). Most of the other databases use ODBC as "native" protocol. Does this mean that Oracle ADO.NET driver - differently from Oracle ODBC - does not "remap" its call to OCI?

Comment: I do not know. Anyway, ADO.NET driver from Microsoft is deprecated and you should not use it. So, this question is actually negligible. I think the more important difference are the less functions you have compared to native drivers.